# How to Read/Write data to an external file (.txt) in Java?

Tags: java

I'm stumped. I can get the prompts, and my entered responses are saved, but only until I exit the program. I cannot recall them to program afterwards and the .txt file is empty. I know I have to move some lines around but I can't figure out which or where and it is driving me insane. I would be incredibly grateful for a hand.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class CornerStoreDranks
{
 public static void main (String [] args)
 {
     Cooler coolerUno = new Cooler();
     int selection;
     char chyea;
     String drank, type, size, stock, doc, infoLine;
     String file = "Drank Management.txt";

    try
    {
        FileReader lincoln = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bread = new BufferedReader(lincoln);
        FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter muscle = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
        PrintWriter printable = new PrintWriter(muscle);

        doc = bread.readLine();

        while(doc!=null)
        {
                StringTokenizer lineReader = new StringTokenizer(doc);

                drank = lineReader.nextToken();
                type = lineReader.nextToken();
                size = lineReader.nextToken();
                stock = lineReader.nextToken();
                infoLine = drank + type + size + stock;

                System.out.println(infoLine);

                doc = bread.readLine();
        }

         do
         {
            System.out.println ("Welcome to your cooler stock management application!\n\n");
            System.out.println ("Please select an option to manage your stock:\n\n");
            System.out.println ("1.  Add a DRAAAANK\n");
                System.out.println ("2.  Display a full list of your DRANKS\n");
            System.out.println ("3.  Update and Exit\n");

            selection = Keyboard.readInt();

            switch (selection)
            {
                case 1: System.out.println ("Enter your DRANK's name:\n");
                    drank = Keyboard.readString();
                    System.out.println ("Enter the type of DRAAAAANK (soda, juice, etc.):\n");
                    type = Keyboard.readString();
                    System.out.println ("Enter the size (in oz.) of your DRANK:\n");
                    size = Keyboard.readString();
                    System.out.println ("Enter the amount you have in stock of this DRANK!\n");
                    stock = Keyboard.readString();

                    coolerUno.stockDrank(drank, type, size, stock);
                    infoLine = drank + type + size + stock;

                    printable.print(infoLine);
                    printable.println();
                    break;

                case 2: System.out.println (coolerUno);
                    break;

                case 3: System.out.println ("Y'all set there? Y/N: \n");
                    chyea = Keyboard.readChar();
                    if (chyea == 'n'||chyea == 'N')
                        selection = 1;
                    else
                        selection = 3;

            }
        }
        while (selection != 3);
        muscle.flush();
        muscle.close();
    }
    catch(IOException exception)
    {
        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Filewriter is not in append mode that means he will overwrite the File every time you start the Program. 
To enable the append mode do this:

```
FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(file,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your anticipation is not right. You have Option "3.  Update and Exit" which means write all updates and exit and you expect to see file written on each step "Y'all set there? Y/N:". It's a contradiction.

You can append output file on each Yes for "Y'all set there? Y/N:" but then option 3 will be "Exit" only.

Or you can leave it as it is but don't expect file to be updated on each step.